# using usercontrol in asp DataGrid Edit Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, user-controls

[Here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx) is the example how to use user control in telerik radGrid's edit form .
Is there any way to use user control in edit form of asp.net DataGrid ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - yes.

Check out this example

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/LivMic/UC_InsideGV02202007133624PM/UC_InsideGV.aspx